# How do I get random element from an array and remove it from there?

Tags: arrays, swift

I know there is a function `randomElement()` that gets random elements and returns it.

```
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
var result = array.randomElement()
print(array) //["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
print(result) //Optional("c")
```

So it works pretty well, but all array stays as it is. How can I remove that random element from an array? Is there a quick way without iterating, finding and removing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select a random index rather than a random element.

```
if let index = array.indices.randomElement() {
    let value = array.remove(at: index)
    // ...
}
```

---

See Alexander's comments below if the intention is to remove all the elements. Removing all the elements this way would be O(n^2), and using `.shuffled()` first would be much faster.

Comment: If you're doing this a lot, it's better to `.shuffle()` first, and just `removeLast()` repeadedly

Comment: Alexander is there a performance difference? I'd like some clarification as to why it's better.

Comment: @ParkerGibson Alexander is correct about the performance impact. My answer is O(n^2) because it has to keep moving elements in the array. Alexander's answer would be O(n log n). Alexander's answer is to a slightly different question (since it modifies the order of the elements that aren't removed), but is a natural next question.

Answer (score 2):

```
extension Array {
    mutating func removeRandom() -> Element? {
        if let index = indices.randomElement() {
            return remove(at: index)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. (voted). I'd use the name extractRandom though, since remove implies "discard" whereas the word "extract" implies "take out". Maybe make the function result discardable so you could ignore it without a compiler warning?

Comment: I made it similar to functions `removeFirst()` and `removeLast()`.

Comment: @DuncanC Most of the `remove*` methods on Collection return the element they remove. The one change I'd make to this is to add `@discardableResult`.

Comment: @RobNapier Please, feel free ro add this;)

Comment: Also, most `remove` methods consider an empty collection to be a programming error (they crash rather than return an optional; the word "pop" is usually used to remove optionally). But it is not absolutely necessary that a custom convenience exactly match existing methods if it is inconvenient to your use.

Comment: Better to extend `RangeReplaceableCollection`. This way it would support strings as well. I would make add `@discardableResult` as well

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
var result = array.randomElement()
if let index = array.firstIndex(of: result ?? "")  {
  array.remove(at: index)
}
print(array) //["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
print(result) //Optional("c")
```